# Aliases for emails

Tags: email, postfix, openldap, iredmail

I'm running an instance of iRedMail (with OpenLDAP), and I want to set it up so it would automatically create aliases for user email, like I register on `junk-site.com`, enter `user-at-junk-site@example.com`, and it would be redirected to `user@example.com` on my server (i.e. use `-at-` as separator). So far I found `recipient_delimiter` parameter for Postfix, but it can only accept pattern of one character (+ by default), and I'm afraid that some services can determine original email, if I gonna specify it like `user+junk-site@example.com` (I assume + is common separator since it is default in Postfix). Is my idea even possible with current software?

Answer (score 2):

You can define multiple delimiters.

From the [doc](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) (emphasis mine):

> The **set** of characters that can separate a user name from its extension

I have defined

```
recipient_delimiter = +-
```

in my config for my private mail service, and this works.

Comment: yeah, you right, but that is not what i meant. In docs specified that " This implementation recognizes one delimiter character". I want separator with multiple characters, like if i gonna write python, it would be `"user-at-junk-site@example.com".split("-at-")`, but from docs i don't see that this could work